# my app running normally but when i am clicking cart button it takes me to first screen from where i started

Tags: java, android

I am making an online food ordering app.My app was running good but when i add cart code it is showing abnormal behaviour like the cart button takes me to first screen i started.following is the cart.java code

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference requests;
TextView txtTotalPrice;
FButton btnPlace;
List<Order> cart=new ArrayList<>();
CartAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    requests = database.getReference("Requests");
    //Init
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listCart);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    txtTotalPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    btnPlace =(FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrder);
    btnPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           showAlertDialog();

        }
    });

    loadlistfood();


}

private void showAlertDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("One more step!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your Address: ");
    final EditText edtAddress = new EditText(Cart.this);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    edtAddress.setLayoutParams(lp);
    alertDialog.setView(edtAddress);//add edt text to alert box
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Request request = new Request(
                    Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                    Common.currentUser.getName(),
                    edtAddress.getText().toString(),
                    txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                    cart
            );
            //submit to firebase
            //we will use system.currntMill to key
            requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .setValue(request);
            //Delete cart
            new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Thank you,Order placed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void loadlistfood() {
    cart=new Database(this).getCarts();
    adapter=new CartAdapter(cart,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //calculate price
    int total=0;
    for(Order order:cart)
        total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
    Locale locale=new Locale("en","US");
    NumberFormat fmt=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));


}
```

Rest i had put a intent in where cart button is put and else i have cartAdapter class and request.java.If you need them i will edit the question.Please help me.
Here is code that take me to cart.java.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference category;
TextView txtFullName;
RecyclerView recycler_menu;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //init firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    category = database.getReference("Category");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent cartIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Cart.class);
            startActivity(cartIntent);
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //set name for user
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
    txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

    //Load menu

    recycler_menu=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_meu);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadMenu();


}

private void loadMenu() {
    adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
            final Category clickItem = model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    //Get category id and send to new Activity
                    Intent foodList=new Intent(Home.this,FoodList.class);
                    foodList.putExtra("CategoryId",adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    startActivity(foodList);
                }
            });

        }
    };
    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {
       // Intent cartIntent = new Intent(Home.this,Cart.class);startActivity(cartIntent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {

    } else if (id == R.id.log_out) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}
Thank you in advance

Comment: The session is not holding..it log out me from my app

Comment: You have a lot of faith in your user's internet connections.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your answer..

Comment: If your user doesn't have an internet connection their order will not make it to the server, Then you are deleting their shopping cart without confirmation from the server that their order was received. They would think their food is coming when the order hasn't been placed.

Comment: but i checked it in working internet connection and still it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, these comments are unrelated to your question. I'm just pointing out erroneous behavior that would cause frustration to some of your users.

Comment: Calling finish() dismisses your activity. Is that what you meant by take you to the first screen?

Comment: i mean whenever i press cart button instead of showing me cart it takes me to the first  screen me log me out

Comment: well, you need to show the relevant code then, i.e. the code that actually transitions you to your cart, and not your cart itself.

Comment: okay ..i'll edit question

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but maybe try using `Home.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` in the line `Intent cartIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Cart.class);`

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Have you added the Cart activity to your manifest?

Comment: yes...it is there

Comment: Sorry, not sure what your problem might be. I'd suggest using the debugger and examining `cartIntent` to see if everything is as you expect it to be.

Comment: is it possible if there could be some problem on database then this problem occurring